# UWP Не могу зашифровать в AES CBC

Tags: c#, uwp, шифрование, aes

Пытаюсь зашифровать byte[] в AES CBC. Конечный буфер (bufferEncrypt) имеет значение NULL.

```
private byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] secretKey = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    IBuffer key = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(secretKey.ToArray()).ToString()).AsBuffer();
    Debug.WriteLine(key.Length);
    SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider algorithmProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbc);
    CryptographicKey cryptographicKey = algorithmProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(key);
    IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(cryptographicKey, data.AsBuffer(), null);

    return bufferEncrypt.ToArray();
}
```

Вот что показывает отладчик (Имя, Значение, Тип):

```
+       this    {Project.Auth}  Project.Auth
+       data    {byte[15]}  byte[]
bufferEncrypt   null    Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer
+       cryptographicKey    {Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicKey}   Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.CryptographicKey
+       key {System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBuffer}    Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer {System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeBuffer}
+       algorithmProvider   {Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider}  Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider
+       SecretKey   Count = 16  System.Collections.Generic.List<byte>
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Вы создали AesCbc, а он требует IV. Вместо IV вы передаете null здесь `CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(cryptographicKey, data.AsBuffer(), null);`

Comment: @Zergatul попробовал сейчас из примера Microsoft инициализировать iv таким образом:
            IBuffer iv = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(algorithmProvider.BlockLength);
            IBuffer bufferEncrypt = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(cryptographicKey, data.AsBuffer(), iv);

bufferEncrypt null :(

Comment: Возможно у вас ключ неправильной длины. Для AES должен быть 16/24/32 байта. Я бы проверил в себя ваш код, но для того что бы его запустить нужен виндовс 10 :(

Comment: @Zergatul, Нет, ключ как раз 16 байт :(

Comment: А какая длина данных, может оно хочет кратную 16 байтам?

Comment: @Zergatul Вот длина всех переменных:
SecretKey Length: 16
key Length: 16
algorithmProvider Length: 16
cryptographicKey Length: 128

Comment: какая длина data? вроде 15 байт, попробуйте выставить 16

Comment: @Zergatul Не помогает :(

Comment: @Zergatul Сейчас попробовал убрать брейкпоинт и получил Exception с сообщением: The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706F8)

Answer (score 0):

Проблему помогли решить [на англоязычном форуме](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985604/c-sharp-uwp-cryptographicengine-encrypt-returns-null/49996466#49996466)

Измененный код описал там, а в CBC варианте нужно было указать IV, как в примере [От Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider)